# Extension Development - Getting the editing author's ID in entry_submission_end hook

Tags: members, extension, member-details

I may just be being thick here - but I can't seem to find this even when debugging the code I am writing.

Here's my scenario:

- I have an extension that does something whenever someone created or updates an entry.
- What I'd like to do is log the user who made edits to an entry

The issue I am running into is when a user (who did not create the original entry) updates an existing entry. I can find the original author's ID in the $meta['author_id'] field, but don't seem to find any reference to the editing author's ID.

Am I missing something, or is this data really not passed to the hook?

Thanks in advance for your help!

MW

Comment: ehm, current user? e.g. session user_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the logged in member use

```
ee()->session->userdata('member_id')
```

or

```
$this->EE->session->userdata('member_id')
```

Comment: Geesh - ever have one of those long days where you make a very very simple solution way over-complicated? Yeah, that must have been yesterday for me. I feel a little silly even having asked this question. But thank you so much for straightening me out. Cheers, Michael